# Cache result of parse.com promise in angular app

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, promise

I'd like my objects to cache the result of some network requests and answer the cached value instead of doing a new request.  [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248768/cache-data-with-resource-promises-pattern) done using angular promises looks a lot like what I'm going for, but I'm not sure how to express it using the Parse.com promise library.  Here's what I'm trying...

```
module.factory('CustomObject', function() {

     var CustomObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomObject", {

         cachedValue: null,

         getValue: function() {
             if (this.cachedValue) return Parse.Promise.as(this.cachedValue);

             return this.functionReturningPromise().then(function (theValue) {
                 this.cachedValue = theValue;
                 return this.cachedValue;
             });
         },
```

My idea is to return a promise whether or not the value is cached.  In the case where the value is cached, that promise is resolved right away.  The problem is, as I follow this in the debugger, I don't seem to get the cached result on the second call.

Comment: Why don't you just cache the original promise and return that?

Comment: I also don't see what Parse.Object gives you here over native JavaScript.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm not totally sure, but their example code does it this way.  At least one thing it does is implement things like save() and destroy().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value is *almost* correct. Your design is correct the only issue you have here is dynamic `this`.

In the context of the `.then` handler, `this` is set to undefined (or the window object), however - since you're using Parse promises and I'm not sure those are Promises/A+ compliant it can be arbitrary things - the HTTP request, or whatever. In strict code and a good promise library - that would have been an exception.

Instead, you can do `CustomObject.cachedValue` explicitly instead of using `this`:

```
var CustomObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomObject", {

    cachedValue: null,

    getValue: function() {
        if (CustomObject.cachedValue) return Parse.Promise.as(this.cachedValue);

        return this.functionReturningPromise().then(function (theValue) {
            CustomObject.cachedValue = theValue;
            return this.cachedValue;
        });
    },
```

If `$q` promises are also possible instead of Parse promises, I'd use those instead:

```
var cachedValue = null;
getValue: function() {
    return $q.when(cachedValue || this.functionReturningPromise()).then(function(theValue){
         return cachedValue = theValue;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I went with.  Just needed to add a close paren before .then.  (Also, I found that Parse.Promise has a when method).

Answer (score 1):

You can just cache the promise and return that

```
module.factory('CustomObject', function() {

  var CustomObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomObject", {

    cachedPromise: null,

    getValue: function() {
        if (!this.cachedPromise) {
            this.cachedPromise = this.functionReturningPromise();
        }
        return this.cachedPromise;
    },
  ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Parse.com promise library, but it could be a plain JS error:
The `this` inside the function is not referring to the Promise object, but to the global object.

Change the code like that:

```
...
getValue: function() {
    if (this.cachedValue) return Parse.Promise.as(this.cachedValue);

    var that = this;
    return this.functionReturningPromise().then(function (theValue) {
        that.cachedValue = theValue;
        return that.cachedValue;
    });
},
```

Comment: Actually, it would refer to the global error if parse.com promises were Promises/A+ complaint, I'm not sure they are - for example, this assumption breaks with jQuery promises.

Comment: Ah.  I see that (and this).  Thanks.